# Cómo hacer una consulta donde me arroje el resultado de 5 campos?

Tags: mysql

en mi tabla quiero hacer una consulta donde me arroje el resultado de 5 campos

tengo una tabla y necesito hacer operaciones entre 5 columnas, lo he logrado con 3 pero las otras 2 no me arrojan nada de resultado....

El campo COD, DESCRIP_ARTICULO, CANT, COST_UNTARIO Y GRAMS_PERS son datos que existen en mi tabla... necesito consultar

```
COST_TOTAL     = CANT*COST_UNTARIO
PORCION_PAX    = CANT*1000/GRAMS_PERS
GRAMS_PAX      = 25*GRAMS_PERS
CANT_SOLICITAR = GRAMS_PAX/1000
SERVICIO_DIA   = CANT_SOLICITAR*7
```

Este es mi código...

```sql
SELECT 
    COD, 
    DESCRIP_ARTICULO,     
    CANT, U_MED,    
    COST_UNTARIO, 
    ROUND(CANT*COST_UNTARIO, 2)    AS COST_TOTAL,GRAMS_PERS, 
    ROUND(CANT*1000/GRAMS_PERS, 2) AS PORCION_PAX, 
    ROUND(25*GRAMS_PERS, 2)    AS GRAMS_PAX, 
    ROUND(GRAMS_PAX/1000, 2)  AS CANT_SOLICITAR, 
    ROUND(CANT_SOLICITAR * 7, 2) AS SERVICIO_DIA 
FROM aceites_y_grasas
```

las tres primeras si me generan el resultado que quiero pero las dos ultimas no... alguien me puede ayudar

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. No sabemos sobre qué datos se está ejecutando esto, los tipos de dato de las columnas en la tabla `aceites_y_grasas` ni la salida esperada para esos datos. Por favor ve a [edit] la pregunta y complétala. Descripción de la tabla y datos de prueba, por favor.

Comment: depende la base de datos, puede que los campos no esten calculados.. mysql admite algunas cosas raras, otras DB te dirian que por ejemplo algunos campos no existen porque son calculados.. proba meter el calculo entero en cada campo, en lugar de usar el nombre del campo, a ver que pasa...

Comment: ¿Será que tienes definidas las columnas GRAMS_PAX y CANT_SOLICITAR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes probar con el siguiente código.

```
SELECT 
    COD, 
    DESCRIP_ARTICULO,     
    CANT, U_MED,    
    COST_UNTARIO, 
    ROUND(CANT*COST_UNTARIO, 2)    AS COST_TOTAL,
    GRAMS_PERS, 
    ROUND(CANT*1000/GRAMS_PERS, 2) AS PORCION_PAX, 
    ROUND(25*GRAMS_PERS, 2)    AS GRAMS_PAX, 
    ROUND((25*GRAMS_PERS)/1000, 2)  AS CANT_SOLICITAR, 
    ROUND(((25*GRAMS_PERS)/1000) * 7, 2) AS SERVICIO_DIA 
FROM aceites_y_grasas
```

Comment: muchas gracias, con tu ayuda logre solucionar ese problema que tenia.... feliz dia